# How to sort two columns in a dataframes when one is blank

Tags: r, sorting

```
ACCT_NUM    ACCT_PURGED_FLG    ACCT_PURGED_DT
   1234                   N 
  12345                   N 
  3456                    N
```

So I am trying to sort `ACCT_NUM` and `ACCT_PURGED_DT` in my dataframe, and I am using below step:

```
rdw_n> rdw_n[with(rdw_n, order(rdw_n$ACCT_NUM, rdw_n$acct_purged_dt)), ]
```

But since the `acct_purged_dt` is blank it throws me the error:

> Error in order(rdw_n$ACCT_NUM, rdw_n$acct_purged_dt) :    argument 2
>   is not a vector

What could be the possible solution to sort these variables even if they are blank or not .

Comment: replace the empty cells with `NA`'s   should work

Comment: `with(rdw_n, if(is.vector(ACCT_PURGED_DT)) rdw_n[order(ACCT_NUM, ACCT_PURGED_DT),]
            else rdw_n[order(ACCT_NUM),])`